# Conflict jar file

Tags: java, android, json, jar, dependencies

I added a jar file in my android application. The file is compiled well and working well.

However the jar file contains Json classes under the `org.jason` package, and it's the same Json package name provided with Android.
When I do an import, the system always choose the Json of Android package and me, I want the Json added with the jar file.

Is there a way to decide which package to import? Either the package provided with Android or the package added with the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `exclude` while importing the library.

```
compile (){
  exclude group: 'x', module: 'y' //by both name and group
}
```

Comment: Yes, i think this is the ideal solution, but i want to exclude the json package from the Android library

Comment: How are you including the library? You should be able to exclude jar using the above method. Otherwise you can goto module dependencies and remove dependency jar.